# React - Photos don't change when page URL changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem.
After changing the URL, the photo on the website does not change. Only refreshing the page will load the correct image. Please help!

```
 import React from 'react';
import '../styles/Header.css';
import header1 from "../images/header1.jpg";
import header2 from "../images/header2.jpg";
import header3 from "../images/header3.jpg";
import header4 from "../images/header4.jpg";
import {Route, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
const Header = () => {
return(
<>

<Route path="/products" exact render={()=>(
    <img src={header1} alt="header1"/>
)}/>
<Route path="/contact" exact render={()=>(
    <img src={header3} alt="header2"/>
)}/>

</>
);
}
export default withRouter(Header);
```

Comment: Could you share a sample of your executable code to codesandbox?

Comment: Page Not Found!

Comment: https://github.com/Piotrko64/router.git okey, now!